# Let $X_1, X_2, ..$ be independent with $E(X_n)=0, var(X_n)={\sigma_{n}}^2$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be independent with $E(X_n)=0, var(X_n)={\sigma_{n}}^2$. How does $X_n/n$ does not converge to $0$ a.s. imply that $1/n\sum_{m=1}^{n}X_m$ does not converge to $0$ a.s.?

Comment: I want to use Kronecker's lemma here but the assumptions in this lemma is already false, so I am not sure if we can apply the lemma here.

Comment: No, you cannot apply this lemma here. Instead, have a look at the increments of your sums. Then try to do the proof via contraposition.

Comment: I am thinking $X_n$ can be negative here, I wonder if we can show $1/n\sum_{m=1}^{n}X_m$ converge to 0, then $X_n/n$ converges to 0?

Comment: $X_n$ is definitely negative somewhere, as it is centered. Yes, this is the better way to prove the claim. Now write down the differences of two consecutive sums and conclude.